# Interface that returns it's self (Cloneable)

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a cloneable interface and am running into some problems getting structs to implement the interface. It appears this is a limit of go which isn't in many other langauges. I'm trying to understand the justification for this limit.

```
var _ Cloneable = test{}

type Cloneable interface {
    Clone() Cloneable
}

type test struct {
}

func (t *test) Clone() *test {
    c := *t
    return &c
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Kugatx3Zpw

Followup question since it still seems weird to me. This also does not compile

```
var _ Cloneable = &test{}

type Cloneable interface {
    Clone() Cloneable
}

type Cloneable2 interface {
    Clone() Cloneable2
}

type test struct {
}

func (t *test) Clone() Cloneable2 {
    c := *t
    return &c
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jlyMDPF1WB

Comment: changing the return type to an interface rather than a struct doesn't make it any less different. The method signatures `Clone() Cloneable` and `Clone() Cloneable2` are not the same.

Comment: That's a choice of the language to not make them both work right? I mean they can be assigned to each other. I guess I am trying to understand the reasoning behind not letting that work

Comment: [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) does not imply that the types are the same.

Comment: Not to mention, those method/function signatures are not assignable to each other: https://play.golang.org/p/45T--iHG0H

Comment: Sure. I am trying to understand the justification for this limit and updated my question. Most other languages I have worked in allow this and go has decided not to. Seems like an odd choice. I would assume there is a reason for it.

Comment: One reason is that different types have different in memory representations. For example a `*test` and `Cloneable` have different memory representations.  When an interface method is called, the call site must understand the memory representation of the returned value to do something with it.

Comment: But you can easily do that conversion anywhere else in go. I can say var t Cloneable := &test{} and the language will convert that for me. Why not do it for a return value to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread which talks about it and the answer seems to be supporting covariant function types would make the language harder to understand for little benefit. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7512

At least they made a conscious decision to not support a feature supported by most other languages. I don't really buy it, but oh well...

Answer (score 4):

To satisfy an interface method, the argument and return types must use the same types used in the interface declaration. The `Clone` method must return a `Cloneable` to satisfy the interface:

```
func (t *test) Clone() Cloneable {
  c := *t
  return &c
}
```

The `Clone` method cannot return a `*test` or `Cloneable2` because these types are not the `Cloneabl`e type.

The pointer type implements the interface:

```
var _ Cloneable = &test{}
```

Because the `test` type must satisfy the `Cloneable` interface for the `Clone` method to compile, this [compile time assertion](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_implements) is not needed.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/qpPGf1hGSX)

(The question is a moving target. This is an answer to two previous edits of the question.)

Comment: For my use case the interface doesn't live in the same package. Do I need to redeclare it in the same package?

Comment: Coming from java it seems weird that I can't be more descriptive about what it is returning.

Comment: Use the one definition of the interface. Do not redeclare it.

Comment: To satisfy an interface method, the argument and return types must be identical to the types used in the interface declaration.

Comment: Sure that works, but that's a pretty big limitation of the language.